# Correlation Metric for Investigating Relationship Between two independent variables

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, multivariate-analysis, spss

I'm working on a study in computer engineering where I'm analyzing the relationship between the dynamic execution count (frequency) of instructions and the corresponding data error rate (SDC) in a nondeterministic fault scenario. Each instruction is injected with faults, and the fault injection process is nondeterministic and uniformly distributed across instructions.

I have a table that includes the frequency of each instruction and its corresponding SDC error rate when we inject faults into. In practical terms, the fault injection process ensures that all instructions are injected with a similar number of faults.

Given the nature of the study, where faults are injected nondeterministically and uniformly, I'm wondering which correlation metric would be most appropriate to investigate whether there is a correlation between the frequency and SDC error rate; so we can conclude that "protecting highly frequently executed instructions will result in high fault coverage, i.e, improve reliability of systems."

I've considered using Spearman's rank correlation coefficient due to its robustness and suitability for non-normally distributed data. However, I'd like to seek advice from the community on whether there might be a more suitable correlation metric for this specific scenario.

Here, is a tiny part of my data

```
instru. freq    SDC
0x103f8 64  3
0x10410 64  2
0x10830 13  7
0x1083c 13  6
0x1086c 13  7
0x108ac 13  7
0x108b0 13  6
0x108bc 13  6
0x10a40 7   6
0x10a48 7   4
0x10a9c 7   5
0x103a0 1   0
0x1049c 1   4
0x104a0 1   4
0x106e0 1   0
0x106e8 1   6
0x10710 1   3
0x10724 1   6
0x10780 1   1
0x1078c 1   0
0x107b8 1   2
0x1090c 1   0
```

Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! By the way you inject faults, don’t you know the faults not to be associated with the two proposed predictor variables? It sounds like the faults are introduced without any regard for them. Have I misinterpreted what you wrote?

Comment: frequency and SDC error rate are two independent variables.

Comment: What correlation do you want to know, and what do the faults have to do with that correlation?

Comment: Do not consider faults, i just want to know which correlation analysis should i use to check if there is a correlation between frequecy values and sdc values. just this.

Answer (score 0):

You only have $4$ **unique** values of $freq$ and 8 **unique** values of $SDC$, and Spearman rank correlation will view the e.g. $6$ values of $13$ as tied values within a "run" starting from rank $15$ and ending at rank $20$, and will therefore assign a rank of $17.5$ to those six values $17.5=(15+20/2)$. Same scheme for the other tied values of $freq$ and $SDC$.  This only really leaves determination of the number of counts for the $4$ and $8$ unique values in each vector.  You could run a $4 \times 8$ chi-squared contingency table test on the two rank vectors; however, Spearman rank correlation will also take a similar appraoch -- so it should be fine.